# Use start and stop function with same button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

With the help of the command button, I am able to disconnect the frame in Tkinter. But is there any way which helps to use the same button to start also?

```
import tkinter as tk
counter = 0
def counter_label(label):
  def count():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    label.config(text=counter)
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Suggestions will be grateful

Comment: What do you mean by start exactly? And your example would be better if you simplified it, like remove the serial dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: whats your file name

Comment: Hi, I have improved my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is overly complicated (my answer), I suggest improving it. But it shows how one could use the same button for both start and stop as well as keeping most of your code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def counter_label(label):
    a = 0
    label.config(text=str(a))
    def count():
        nonlocal a
        label.config(text=str(a))
        a += 1
        label.after(1000, count)
    return count

def start_stop(root, btn_text, counter):
    first = True
    def call():
        nonlocal first
        if first:
            counter()
            first = False
            btn_text.set('Stop')
        else:
            root.destroy()
    return call

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter = counter_label(label)
btn_text = tk.StringVar()
button = tk.Button(root, textvariable=btn_text, width=25, command=start_stop(root, btn_text, counter))
btn_text.set('Start')
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simple use an if/else statement to check if the buttons text is `Start` or `Stop` then change a Boolean variable that controls the counter while also update the text on the button.

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0
active_counter = False


def count():
    if active_counter:
        global counter
        counter += 1
        label.config(text=counter)
        label.after(1000, count)


def start_stop():
    global active_counter
    if button['text'] == 'Start':
        active_counter = True
        count()
        button.config(text="Stop")
    else:
        active_counter = False
        button.config(text="Start")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Start', width=25, command=start_stop)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is an OOP example as well:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Counting Seconds")
        self.counter = 0
        self.active_counter = False
        self.label = tk.Label(self, fg="green")
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', width=25, command=self.start_stop)
        self.button.pack()

    def count(self):
        if self.active_counter:
            self.counter += 1
            self.label.config(text=self.counter)
            self.label.after(1000, self.count)

    def start_stop(self):
        if self.button['text'] == 'Start':
            self.active_counter = True
            self.count()
            self.button.config(text="Stop")
        else:
            self.active_counter = False
            self.button.config(text="Start")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the reply, the code is working with above example but What If I have the array with values receiving from a serial port like `counter = ['22.34', '22.35', '26.66']` and I want to display and update the label text. For example `label1 = label.config(text=counter[0]), label2 = label.config(text=counter[1]), label3 = label.config(text=counter[2])` something like this.

Comment: @varuljain sure I see no reason you cannot do that.