# NameError in functions using global variable

Tags: python, namespaces

I try to stop a .after function i tkinter in python 3.6, but have probems with namspace of variables. I get NameError: "name 'counter' is not defined" when I use this code:

I read this excellent post, from where I got the idea of using two buttons instead of one.
[Use start and stop function with same button in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461292/use-start-and-stop-function-with-same-button-in-tkinter)

```
def count(ac,rs):
    if ac:
        global counter
        counter += 1
        label.config(text=counter)
        label.after(1000, count)
        if rs:
            counter = 0
            counter += 1
            count()

def start():
    ac = True
    rs=False
    count(ac,rs)

def stop():
    ac = False
    label.configure(text='0')
    rs = True
    count(ac,rs)
```

Since I declare the variable counter in the count() function, I don't understand the NameError.

Comment: the global keyword does not define the variable and on the next line you're assuming it is already defined, because you're effectively doing `counter = counter + 1`

Comment: You should read the "exellent post" you linked to more carefully. Add the line `counter = 0` before `def count(ac,rs):` so that the variable is initialised properly.

Comment: Thanks for input. I skipped the parameters, and initialized the ac (active counter) and rs (restart) variables as global. Now I try to call count() function with the start() function, where the ac is set True, but things are not happening in the count() function. Would you possibly give a working example?

Comment: ...and of course I put the counter variable  before def count() as advised

Comment: As I said, I'm still stuck on this. Someone who have mercy?